# Equal width progress bar labels and center vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to "push" all the progress bars to the right while centering them vertically so that it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried giving using inline-block with the first-bar class and giving it a width which works, but my progress bars wont center vertically with the  text if I do it that way.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dueldrawer8/n1aaa41b/1/)**

```css
.first-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="software-info">
  <h3>Software</h3>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Indesign CC</span>
    <progress value="100" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="90" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Photoshop CC</span>
    <progress value="80" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="70" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>HTML 5</span>
    <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>CSS 3</span>
    <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply set `width` or `min-width` to the `<span>`, or the flexbox way `flex` or `flex-basic` with a value that can hold all text without wrapping.

Alternatively, you can use CSS table layout (added a wrapper div `first-bars`), all cells in the same column will be equal width automatically, therefore no fixed width value is needed.

```css
.first-bars {
  display: table;
}

.first-bar {
  display: table-row;
}

.first-bar span,
.first-bar progress {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.first-bar span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="software-info">
  <h3>Software</h3>
  <div class="first-bars">
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>Indesign CC</span>
      <progress value="100" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>Illustrator CC</span>
      <progress value="90" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>Photoshop CC</span>
      <progress value="80" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>Illustrator CC</span>
      <progress value="70" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>HTML 5</span>
      <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="first-bar">
      <span>CSS 3</span>
      <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The inline block approach also works, you just need to set `vertical-align: middle;` to reset the default value `baseline`.

```css
.first-bar span,
.first-bar progress {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="software-info">
  <h3>Software</h3>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Indesign CC</span>
    <progress value="100" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="90" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Photoshop CC</span>
    <progress value="80" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="70" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>HTML 5</span>
    <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>CSS 3</span>
    <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent! What I was looking for. It seems a common theme is just I need to add width which seems to give them all the same width therefore equaling or centering them out vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `span` a width value.

```css
.first-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-bar span {
  min-width: 7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="software-info">
  <h3>Software</h3>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Indesign CC</span>
    <progress value="100" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="90" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Photoshop CC</span>
    <progress value="80" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>Illustrator CC</span>
    <progress value="70" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>HTML 5</span>
    <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="first-bar">
    <span>CSS 3</span>
    <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```